# Как в WinForms сделать Button и TextBox с закругленными углами?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать кнопку в WinForms с закругленными углами?Пример кнопки приложил[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нужно создавать свой класс, который наследует от Button и переопределить в нем OnPaint метод

Comment: Пример на codeproject https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/315013/WinForms-Button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо, Максим. Твой комментарий - лучший ответ

```
public class RoundButton : Control
{
    public Color BackColor2 { get; set; }
    public Color ButtonBorderColor { get; set; }
    public int ButtonRoundRadius { get; set; }

    public Color ButtonHighlightColor { get; set; }
    public Color ButtonHighlightColor2 { get; set; }
    public Color ButtonHighlightForeColor { get; set; }

    public Color ButtonPressedColor { get; set; }
    public Color ButtonPressedColor2 { get; set; }
    public Color ButtonPressedForeColor { get; set; }

    private bool IsHighlighted;
    private bool IsPressed;

    public RoundButton()
    {
        Size = new Size(100, 40);
        ButtonRoundRadius = 30;
        BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
        BackColor2 = Color.Silver;
        ButtonBorderColor = Color.Black;
        ButtonHighlightColor = Color.Orange;
        ButtonHighlightColor2 = Color.OrangeRed;
        ButtonHighlightForeColor = Color.Black;

        ButtonPressedColor = Color.Red;
        ButtonPressedColor2 = Color.Maroon;
        ButtonPressedForeColor = Color.White;
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
            createParams.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; // WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            return createParams;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        var foreColor = IsPressed ? ButtonPressedForeColor : IsHighlighted ? ButtonHighlightForeColor : ForeColor;
        var backColor = IsPressed ? ButtonPressedColor : IsHighlighted ? ButtonHighlightColor : BackColor;
        var backColor2 = IsPressed ? ButtonPressedColor2 : IsHighlighted ? ButtonHighlightColor2 : BackColor2;


        using (var pen = new Pen(ButtonBorderColor, 1))
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, Path);

        using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, backColor, backColor2, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
            e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, Path);

        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(foreColor))
        {
            var sf = new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center };
            var rect = ClientRectangle;
            rect.Inflate(-4, -4);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, rect, sf);
        }

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        IsHighlighted = true;
        Parent.Invalidate(Bounds, false);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        IsHighlighted = false;
        IsPressed = false;
        Parent.Invalidate(Bounds, false);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        Parent.Invalidate(Bounds, false);
        Invalidate();
        IsPressed = true;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        Parent.Invalidate(Bounds, false);
        Invalidate();
        IsPressed = false;
    }

    protected GraphicsPath Path 
    {
        get
        {
            var rect = ClientRectangle;
            rect.Inflate(-1, -1);
            return GetRoundedRectangle(rect, ButtonRoundRadius);
        }
    }

    public static GraphicsPath GetRoundedRectangle(Rectangle rect, int d)
    {
        var gp = new GraphicsPath();

        gp.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Y, d, d, 180, 90);
        gp.AddArc(rect.X + rect.Width - d, rect.Y, d, d, 270, 90);
        gp.AddArc(rect.X + rect.Width - d, rect.Y + rect.Height - d, d, d, 0, 90);
        gp.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Y + rect.Height - d, d, d, 90, 90);
        gp.CloseFigure();

        return gp;
    }
}
```

[Источник](http://www.cyberforum.ru/post9872749.html)

Comment: Только это не мой вариант, а `Storm23` с другого форума.

Answer (score 5):

Создаем класс `RoundButton`:

```
public class RoundButton : Button
{
    GraphicsPath GetRoundPath(RectangleF Rect, int radius)
    {
        float r2 = radius / 2f;
        GraphicsPath GraphPath = new GraphicsPath();

        GraphPath.AddArc(Rect.X, Rect.Y, radius, radius, 180, 90);
        GraphPath.AddLine(Rect.X + r2, Rect.Y, Rect.Width - r2, Rect.Y);
        GraphPath.AddArc(Rect.X + Rect.Width - radius, Rect.Y, radius, radius, 270, 90);
        GraphPath.AddLine(Rect.Width, Rect.Y + r2, Rect.Width, Rect.Height - r2);
        GraphPath.AddArc(Rect.X + Rect.Width - radius,
                            Rect.Y + Rect.Height - radius, radius, radius, 0, 90);
        GraphPath.AddLine(Rect.Width - r2, Rect.Height, Rect.X + r2, Rect.Height);
        GraphPath.AddArc(Rect.X, Rect.Y + Rect.Height - radius, radius, radius, 90, 90);
        GraphPath.AddLine(Rect.X, Rect.Height - r2, Rect.X, Rect.Y + r2);

        GraphPath.CloseFigure();
        return GraphPath;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        RectangleF Rect = new RectangleF(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
        GraphicsPath GraphPath = GetRoundPath(Rect, 50);

        this.Region = new Region(GraphPath);
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Lime, 1.75f))
        {
            pen.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset;
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, GraphPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Находим в ToolBox `RoundButton` и перетаскиваем на форму:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Неэффективно при каждом событии отрисовки вычислять `GraphicsPath` и задавать `Region`.

Comment: Какой есть более эффективный вариант?

Comment: А почему края не гладкие, как на скриншоте который выложил ТС?

Comment: Там не только края, но и тень есть на кнопке. Но вопрос был в том как закруглить.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, вот, это то, что нужно: `http://www.cyberforum.ru/post9872749.html`

Comment: Да, предложенный вариант куда лучше