# Как в WinForms сделать TextBox cзакругленными углами?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как в WinForms сделать TextBox cзакругленными углами? Пробовал по аналогии как в примере с button. Ошибок нет, углы не закругляет. С другими контролами получается.Что не так?

```
public class RoundTextBox : TextBox
    {

    public Color BackColor2 { get; set; }
    public Color TextBoxBorderColor { get; set; }
    public int TextBoxRoundRadius { get; set; }

    public Color TextBoxHighlightColor { get; set; }
    public Color TextBoxHighlightColor2 { get; set; }
    public Color TextBoxHighlightForeColor { get; set; }

    public Color TextBoxPressedColor { get; set; }
    public Color TextBoxPressedColor2 { get; set; }
    public Color TextBoxPressedForeColor { get; set; }

    private bool IsHighlighted;
    private bool IsPressed;

    public RoundTextBox()
    {
        Size = new Size(100, 40);
        TextBoxRoundRadius = 30;
        BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
        BackColor2 = Color.Silver;
        TextBoxBorderColor = Color.Black;
        TextBoxHighlightColor = Color.Orange;
        TextBoxHighlightColor2 = Color.OrangeRed;
        TextBoxHighlightForeColor = Color.Black;

        TextBoxPressedColor = Color.Red;
        TextBoxPressedColor2 = Color.Maroon;
        TextBoxPressedForeColor = Color.White;
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
            createParams.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; // WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            return createParams;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        var foreColor = IsPressed ? TextBoxPressedForeColor : IsHighlighted ? TextBoxHighlightForeColor : ForeColor;
        var backColor = IsPressed ? TextBoxPressedColor : IsHighlighted ? TextBoxHighlightColor : BackColor;
        var backColor2 = IsPressed ? TextBoxPressedColor2 : IsHighlighted ? TextBoxHighlightColor2 : BackColor2;


        using (var pen = new Pen(TextBoxBorderColor, 1))
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, Path);

        using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, backColor, backColor2, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
            e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, Path);

        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(foreColor))
        {
            var sf = new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center };
            var rect = ClientRectangle;
            rect.Inflate(-4, -4);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, rect, sf);
        }

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        IsHighlighted = true;
        Parent.Invalidate(Bounds, false);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        IsHighlighted = false;
        IsPressed = false;
        Parent.Invalidate(Bounds, false);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        Parent.Invalidate(Bounds, false);
        Invalidate();
        IsPressed = true;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        Parent.Invalidate(Bounds, false);
        Invalidate();
        IsPressed = false;
    }

    protected GraphicsPath Path
    {
        get
        {
            var rect = ClientRectangle;
            rect.Inflate(-1, -1);
            return GetRoundedRectangle(rect, TextBoxRoundRadius);
        }
    }

    public static GraphicsPath GetRoundedRectangle(Rectangle rect, int d)
    {
        var gp = new GraphicsPath();

        gp.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Y, d, d, 180, 90);
        gp.AddArc(rect.X + rect.Width - d, rect.Y, d, d, 270, 90);
        gp.AddArc(rect.X + rect.Width - d, rect.Y + rect.Height - d, d, d, 0, 90);
        gp.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Y + rect.Height - d, d, d, 90, 90);
        gp.CloseFigure();

        return gp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы же уже спрашивали и получили ответ на этот вопрос ?

Comment: @koks_rs  вот! Про этот вопрос о button'е я в своем ответе и говорил)

Comment: Мой вам совет: не нужны вам и пользователям вашего софта все эти закругленные кнопочки и прочие контролы. Посмотрите, например, на этот сайт и найдите хоть один такой элемент. Сделайте выводы.

Comment: Всех дизайнеров отправлять на этот сайт?

Comment: Большинство отправлять в биореактор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать Graphics path, Вызываете после инициализации компонентов TextBoxElipse(textbox1);

```
    void TextBoxElipse(TextBox t)
    {
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gPath = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        gPath.AddEllipse(0, 0, t.Width, t.Height);
        t.Region = new Region(gPath);
        gPath.Dispose();
    }
```

Но некрасиво вышло,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если добавить проверки, добавлять пробелы нужные и тому подобное, можно сделать и красиво.

Если лень, советую поискать по любому другому контролу, например [закругление буттона недавно был вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600577/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-winforms-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-button-%D0%B8-textbox-%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8), очень качественно ему ответили, возможно возьмете от туда логику.

Comment: Как это сделать методом AddArc, чтобы углы были более красиво закруглены?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
        (
            int nLeftRect, // x-coordinate of upper-left corner
            int nTopRect, // y-coordinate of upper-left corner
            int nRightRect, // x-coordinate of lower-right corner
            int nBottomRect, // y-coordinate of lower-right corner
            int nWidthEllipse, // height of ellipse
            int nHeightEllipse // width of ellipse
         );

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height, 20, 20));
        }
    }
}
```

[Здесь](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/15730/roundbutton-windows-control-ever-decreasing-circle) посмотрите.

Comment: Стоит ли того WF, чтобы отказываться от WPF ?)

Comment: Дико извиняюсь за невежество в WPF, но грид меня там убил, когда пытался программно вставить в столбец-combobox, пришлось делать, как в 1с^^ при клике открывать отдельное окно для редактирование записи. Так, что думаю, автор не зря решил уйти с него)) Если не нужно часто менять графику и подгружать её динамически, весьма обосновано.